# Proof for cosine formula for the dot product

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

I'm trying to understand how the geometric and algebraic formulas for the dot product are in equal. In doing so, I first am going through the proof that $V \cdot W = ||V||||W|| \cos{\theta}$

Here's [the proof](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Cosine_Formula_for_Dot_Product) and I don't follow $||V-W||^2 = (V-W) \cdot (V-W)$. It site's the rule used is "dot product of a vector with itself" but this doesn't make sense since V and W aren't the same vectors. Where am I getting confused?

LaTeX isn't working for me, I tried on FireFox and IE. Is it working for other people? It doesn't display properly.

Comment: The vector they're taking is $U=V-W$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments the vector the book is referring to is $V-W$ which is generally not the same vector as $V$ or $W$. However its easy to prove the statement just by breaking the problem into components which is how most statements involving vectors are proven.

$$ (V-W) \cdot (V-W) $$ $$= [ (V_x-W_x) \vec{i} + (V_y-W_y)\vec{j} +(V_z-W_z)\vec{k}] \cdot [ (V_x-W_x) \vec{i} + (V_y-W_y)\vec{j} +(V_z-W_z)\vec{k}] $$ $$=  (V_x-W_x)^2 + (V_y-W_y)^2 +(V_z-W_z)^2 $$ $$= \left(\sqrt{(V_x-W_x)^2 + (V_y-W_y)^2 +(V_z-W_z)^2}\right)^2= || V-W||^2$$